# Python - online data collection

Tags: python

I need to test application with testers around the world. I've written class for saving important data to the file. What is the easiest way to send this file (or simple coded string) from tester's pc to me (I suppose to some server, or a special mail?) without interrupting the tester in a Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is a `Version Control System` such as `mercurial`, `git`, etc